# WSO2 EI Unit testing in Jenkins is failing with error "Exception occurred while running test cases: Connection refused for service in port - 9008"

Tags: maven, jenkins, cicd, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I have created a REST API with Unit test cases and the same worked fine while executing from Integration Studio and checked the same by executing Maven command (mvn test -DtestServerType=local -DtestServerPath="D:\Softwares\WSO2-Integration-Studio-8.2.0-win32-x86_64\IntegrationStudio\runtime\microesb\bin\micro-integrator.bat") the unit test case executed successfully.

[Mvn Command Execution through CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tx9u4.png)

But While configuring the same in Jenkins as below
is resulting with error "Connection refused for service in port - 9008"

[Jenkins build step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIvZN.png)

Error In Jenkins Console:

[Error In Jenkins Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJxYK.png)

I tried with other Ports as well and checked the network level exceptions but no luck